# Why method of 'events' does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make what ActiveRecord validation errors highlighted in the browser takes a lesson from ASCIIcasts.
This is my partial _errors_messages

```
<% if event.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
  <h2><%= pluralize(event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

this is my html file which is generated form

```
<%= form_for event, html: { class: "event-form" } do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @event %>  
  <% unless current_user %>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <%= label :email, "Enter your email:" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :email, "",class: "form-control" %>
```

and this error browser show

```
undefined local variable or method `event' for #<#<Class:0x007f117cc78c30>:0x007f117cdf5c48>
```

Comment: Have describe `event` as object in your controller?

Comment: yes, there is http://pastebin.com/WDNf5HQM

Comment: can't access `pastebin` provide http://pastie.org/

Comment: http://pastie.org/9572388

Answer (score 1):

`event` should be an instance variable in the controller, e.g., `@event`.

Comment: led to another error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Comment: @weare138 ... You need to instantiate an object.